# Convert date Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 UTC 2023 to another format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I got an issue in SQL Server when converting the date into another date format.

I have a column `AuthDate` with datatype `text`. The value of `AuthDate` is a date with this format

```
Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 UTC 2023
```

The question is how can I compare `AuthDate` in SQL Server like this example:

```
Select * 
From table_a 
Where AuthDate >= current_timestamp
```

I try to convert it first using `CONVERT`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 UTC 2023', 109);
```

but I get an error

> [S0001][241] Line 1: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

**Note**: when converting in golang it can using `time.UnixDate` as a layout

I expected that I can change the format when running the query and compare it with some other date value like this :

```
where AuthDate >= current_timestamp
```

I've read the convert style in [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but it doesn't work

Comment: If the AuthDate is a string in the database. You can not compare it with another date in string format and get the right result. You should do the other way around. You should convert the AuthDate column value to Date and then compare it against current_timestamp.

Comment: `with **text ** as a datatype`  that's the problem. Change it to an actual date type. Dates have no format, they're binary values. There's no if or but or maybe or in a perfect world. This is a critical bug. `how can i compare AuthDate` you can't, in any language or database, not just SQL Server. That's  a string, not a date, and strings are compared using lexical rules.

Comment: `converting in golang it can using time.UnixDate as a layout` dates have no layout or format in Go either. Go, like almost all programming languages, natively supports dates as actual types.

Comment: As for converting, you're using a completely custom format - no format puts the year *after* the timezone. There's no standard style or culture that could handle this. You'll have to write explicit parsing code. TSQL is weak in text parsing so the best option is to use a client language, eg C#, Java, Python

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos One never knows, maybe there's a timezone at UTC+2023 hours?

Comment: Are you really using the `text` datatype? Aside from any string datatype just being wrong for storing dates, the text datatype has been deprecated for almost 20 years now.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

As your AuthDate column is in text format, you need to convert it into datetime format to compare current timestamp. You can use `Convert` function for this purpose. You need to take out month, day and year from your value first using `substring` function. Please see the example below:

```
DECLARE @AuthDate VARCHAR(150) = 'Thu Feb 02 00:00:00 UTC 2023'
DECLARE @AuthDate_dt DATETIME;
SELECT @AuthDate_dt = CONVERT(datetime, SUBSTRING(@x, 5, 11) + RIGHT(@x, 5), 100)
```

Then you can do like:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN @AuthDate_dt  >= GETDATE() THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END) result
```

Comment: Dates are binary types, they have no format

Comment: This converts the date and time to the server local time - but this is UTC date and time and that will not be correct for comparing to current_timestamp or GETDATE().  Once converted - you can either convert the UTC to local and then compare to current_timestamp, or you can compare to SYSUTCDATETIME().

Comment: There are ways to construct a date from parts, eg using `datetimefromparts` or even better `datetimeoffsetfromparts`. This should only be used to solve the *real* problem though, by creating a proper date-type column and parsing the old data. Otherwise this just covers things up

Comment: Conversion to different timezones can be done using the `AT TIME ZONE` clause that's available in all SQL Server versions in mainstream support and even older, going back to 2016

Comment: thank u for the answer @eray-balkanli, i think the answer is the possible solution. if the datatype is string format we need to manually parse out the month, day and year one by one and converting into appropriate date format such as y-m-d h:m:s.